# Storing large object to InProc session rather than reloading on every page

Tags: asp.net

This is my first post/question so please let me know if/how I can improve it. I found similar questions but nothing quite covered this.

When you store to InProc session you're just storing a reference to the data. So, if I have a public property foo, and I store it in Session("foo") = foo, then I haven't really taken up any additional memory (aside from the 32/64 bits used by the pointer)?

In my case, we are currently reloading foo on every page of our website, so if I were to instead store it in session, then it should be taking the same about of space, but not needing to reload on every page. I'm seeing a lot of people say not to store large objects in session, but if that large object already exists, what difference does it make to have a pointer to it? Of course I would remove the object from session the moment it was no longer needed.

The data we are trying to store is an object specific to the user's current work, but not user data. As an analogy, say the user was a car dealer, and he is looking at all the data for a particular customer. We have multiple pages for this customer, and we want to keep all the customer info loaded on each page, All the customer data is stored in a single xml data column in a SQL table, which we parse on every page.

We have tried binary serialization instead of parsing xml, so we could store with session in state server mode, but we found the performance to actually be worse.

We are running on a single web server.

Comment: You may want to add details about your problem from your comments to make this a better question. Specifically this question lacks details about whay you've tried and what this object is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, no. When you store something in the session state all the data required to store that object is consumed by the website process(s). Just because .NET treats variables like references doesn't mean it actually uses less memory than a no-GC language. It just means that copying that variable around is done efficiently without using reference operators or pointers.

Your question is a bit vague, but you have a few options for persisting data:

1) Send the data to the client as JSON and store it on the browser if it should be per-user and is needed more on the client side than the server side. You can then send pieces of the data with different requests if you need to (put it in hidden fields if you have to use ASPX web forms).

2) Store it in the session state if it is a small bit of per user data.

3) Store it in the ASP.NET cache if it is large and common to all users, see here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx).

4) If it is large and user-specific that is used primarily on the server then you have more of a performance problem. You should see if you can break out any user specific stuff from static stuff. If you do that and its still large then a database may not be a bad solution. If you are already using DB calls in your application then looking up this data on every request won't cause too much overhead and you won't have to regenerate it from scratch (You should only do this if the data takes a considerable time to generate as a DB call could be slower than just regenerating the data itself). I recommend writing some sort of middleware (HttpModule or OwinMiddleware) that uses whatever user Identity you use for auth to look up the data and then set it on the HttpContext.Current.Items collection. This way the data is usable for the entire request and you can add logic in the middleware to figure out when to set it.

I would think that having a large chunk of user-specific data would be a red flag as user data should just be a list of what the user can/can't do and what their preferences are.

If this is static data then its super simple. The application cache is what you want. The only complications would be if you have multiple servers that need synced data.

Comment: Thank you. It is large and specific to the user's current work (not user data exactly). Currently it is already stored in a database as xml. The issue is that the performance of parsing hat xml and creating our object is too slow. We have already tried increasing the performance and can't get where we need to be. It would take a considerable refactor to increase the performance of loading the objects any more. I guess my question is, if we already have that amount of data loaded on every page for every user, would it really make a difference to the performance to store it in session?

Comment: If its the XML parsing that is killing you, have you looked into serializing the parsed object into a binary stream and storing that in the DB? It may be considerably faster to reload. .NET provides some serialization interfaces. But if you only have a few users and aren't worried about scaling up then the session probably won't hurt you too much. But make any pages/handlers that don't update the object use the read-only session state.

Comment: We have about 2000 users, typically a fraction would actually be active at any time. I have looked into serialisaztion into binary, but the object contains so many objects that it would be considerable effort to update everything so we were able to do that. Every page would update the object, but thanks for the tip on read-only.

Comment: Oh, it won't let me edit so I'll just have to correct myself. We actually did try to use binary serialization. It had worse performance than our xml parsing. It would take a lot of effort to update to use the built in xml serialization (we are parsing it using System.Xml.Linq, not the xml serializer), so we didn't bother testing that. I couldn't imagine it would have better performance than binary serialization anyway.

Comment: And I guess what I am saying on the memory aspect, is that just in this particular case, it seems that it wouldn't be taking more memory; it's just the memory would be persisted longer. Anytime the code is running, this object exists, so if I store it in session it would just mean that the data is still there after the server side code has finished running. So instead of 10mb of space on the server taken while the code runs and then freed when it stops, the 10mb is constantly used. Is that an acccurate understanding? Or does storing it in session double it?

Comment: I think you are right about that. But in realtime storing stuff in session state may result in RAM usage orders of magnitude greater than if you used the DB. For instance, if 10 users are logged in and each request takes 1 second and each user makes 1 request per second then you will be storing 1 user object in RAM at any given point if you read from the DB. With session you will always be storing all 10. Its the old question, do you have more RAM or CPU power? Right now it sounds like you have more RAM.

Comment: This whole discussion assumes you are running your app on 1 server though.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Yes it is on one server. I agree with your analysis and appreciate the input.